# Zeep setting my credentials values to NotSet

Tags: xmlhttprequest, zeep

I am trying to create a python soap client with zeep but run into the following problem:
The credentials values that I set in the python dictionary are set by Zeep to NotSet and therefore I am getting: "Fault: Invalid credentials entered by user NotSet"
I will paste the request that I am writing and then the request as sent by zeep where my clientId and password are changed to NotSet.

```
request_data={'language':'EN',
                "identification": {"clientId":"something", "password":"something","customerKey":"" },...
from zeep import Client
from zeep.plugins import HistoryPlugin
history = HistoryPlugin()
wsdl='https://api.infinitehotel.com/gekko-front/ws/v2_4/AvailabilityService?wsdl'
client = Client(wsdl,plugins=[history])
response = client.service.hotelAvailability(**request_data)
```

The request that zeep is sending:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap-env:Body><ns0:hotelAvailability xmlns:ns0="http://webservice.gekko-holding.com/v2_4"><language>EN</language><identification clientId="NotSet" password="NotSet" customerKey=""/>
```

As you can see it is modifying only the values of clientId and password to "NotSet"

Can you please indicate a way to solve this problem?
Thank you